# Strange behavior of setOnMouseExited/Entered

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a grid composed of boxes. Box extends region and only have a background and a pref size.
I put listeners on every box in order to change the background when mouseEntered, the problem is the listener don't stop. If I print something in the console it keeps doing it if I'm moving the mouse inside the box. I searched so first and found I could use setDisable and setMouseTransparent but no luck. Witch setDisable I'm not in a forever loop anymore but the color doesn't change (or it's rly quick and revert to the original color even if I don't exit the box with the mouse)

```
                c.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                    c.setStyle("-fx-background-color: darkgray");
                    c.setDisable(true);
                    event.consume();
                }
            });
            c.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    c.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white");
                    System.out.println("test");
                    c.setDisable(true);
                    event.consume();
                }
            });
```

Forgot to mention it but c is a box and the box class extends Region

Comment: Just setting the style (not calling `setDisable()` or `event.consume()`) in the handlers works fine for me. Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe. However, there is another way to do what you need.

If you add a style class to the boxes (`c.getStyleClass().add("box");` or just `getStyleClass().add("box");` in the `Box` constructor), then you just need the following in an external CSS file:

```
.box {
    -fx-background-color: white ;
}
.box:hover {
    -fx-background-color: darkgrey ;
}
```

Then get rid of the mouse handlers entirely.